# scaling each element in a tuple in python

Tags: python, tuples, operation

I have a tuple type data as below:

```
x =  (((-300, 49.3878), (-300, 400), (-220.045, 400), (-169.193, 204.22), (-300, 49.3878)))
```

I need scale each element in the tuple by dividing 100. That is, the output result should be:

```
x'= (((-3.00, 0.493878), (-3.00, 4.00), (-2.20045, 4.00), (-1.69193, 2.0422), (-3.00, 0.493878)))
```

Could someone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a nested [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) as shown below.

```
x =  (((-300, 49.3878), (-300, 400), (-220.045, 400), (-169.193, 204.22), (-300, 49.3878)))

y = tuple(tuple(i / 100.0 for i in inner) for inner in x)

# You can remove the tuple and instead use [] if you don't mind it being a list.
y_list = [[i / 100.0 for i in inner] for inner in x]
```

Comment: It might be worth dividing by `100.0` if you're using python 2 to stop any integers (other than multiples of 100) being divided 'incorrectly'.